# Golem deploy in docker : %>% not fund

Tags: r, docker, shiny, golem

I migrate my shiny app in dockerised golem app.
I have a problem in the use of pipe.
With this line :

```
plotly::plot_ly(tabPieTension, labels = ~cat, values = ~valeur, type = 'pie', sort = FALSE) %>%
     plotly::layout(title = "Delta tension (Baisse de tension décharge)")
```

My app run well in Rstudio local.
I build the .tar.gz without error.
I build the docker image without problem (and dplyr is well installed)
but when I run the image I have

> error : could not find function "%>%"

Seems that dplyr is not recognized.
I try change to dplyr::%>% but the build won't work.

Is someone has an idea of my error ?
Many thanks !

Comment: load the library instead https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/pipe-r-tutorial

Comment: Just because a library is installed, that doesn't mean it's been loaded. Did you load dplyr?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As golem apps are packages, you should declare all your dependencies the same way as in a package, especially if you are dockerizing the app.

That being said, calling library() inside the app server won't be the good practice for a golem app. For adding a dep, you can add them to your DESCRIPTION with usethis::use_package("package"), then add the correct roxygen tags where it's needed in the app.

If you need the pipe thought, you can simply call usethis::use_pipe() and you'll get all the infrastructure you need :)

More information about deps and packages:
http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/description.html#dependencies

Comment: I might be doing something wrong because after running ```usethis::use_pipe()``` or  ```usethis::use_package("magrittr, min_version=TRUE)```  in the 02_dev.R and verifying the Imports from the DESCRIPTION.R, I still get the same error related to the ```'%>%'```.

Comment: Are all your files in the R/ folder containing functions? If you have code that is executed (you shouldn't), then it might be that magrittr is not loaded when you run these files.

Answer (score 0):

Did you clear your working space and then tested locally? Maybe you loaded the package once and have not done that in the actual code. Did you check to put `library(dplyr)` in the server section?

Comment: Call library(dplyr) in the server section works. Thanks !

Comment: It's a little bit surprising because all the other packages are working without it and dplyr is declare like the others. Golem framework automations are here to manage these simple questions.

For my comprehension, is prepending the call of packages'functions with packageName:: exempt of launch the library manualy ? In my case it's the only difference between the use of the 2 packages (dplyr and plotly).

Comment: If your question is if `dplyr::select()` is the same as `library(dplyr); select()`, then the answer is no. The first is use to avoid namespace collsions. Just imagine having two packages each with a function with the same name, e.g. `filter()`. This is the case for the `stats` and the `dplyr` package. Whenever you load the package it actually warns you about it this, try it out. If the the function `filter()` is called by you, R cannot know if you mean `stats::filter()` or `dplyr::filter()`. This is why you should specify it.